# .each loop not executing

Tags: ruby

I have this snippet of code:

```
File.open(input, "w+").each do |line|
   puts "Enter line content, or \"-EOF-\" to stop inputting."
   input = gets.chomp
   if input == "-EOF-"
        break
   else
       line.puts input
   end
end
```

It creates the file, but it doesn't do anything else that's specified. Why is that?

Comment: Even if that block were executed, it'd crash. Strings don't have [public] method `puts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It creates the file, but it doesn't do anything else that's specified. Why is that?

Because you call `File.open(...).each` instead of just `File.open(...)` – you want to open the file, not traverse its content.

That aside, you don't have to invent your own [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) handling. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will generate an EOF indicator which in turn results in [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returning `nil`.

This allows you to have a simple loop:

```
File.open(input, 'w+') do |file|
  puts 'Enter lines, or hit "Ctrl-D" to stop inputting.'
  while line = gets
    file.puts line
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating a new file and that's empty, so no lines, no blocks executed. If you want to enter into the loop, that file should contain some lines and you need to open it in append mode

```
File.open(input, "a+")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems here.

One, you're using the filename variable `File.open(input...` also as a variable for what the user enters (`input = gets.chomp`). Don't do that.

Secondly, when you open an existing file for writing with `w+` you truncate it to zero length. Your loop is actually a block at that point. If you were reading, that would be a different story.

Try opening the file and assigning it to a variable:

```
f = File.new(input,  "w+")
```

Then run a loop (`begin...end while`) that gets input and writes it to `f` as follows:

```
userstuff = gets.chomp
f.write(userstuff)
```

Don't forget to close the file when you are finished writing to it:

```
f.close
```

Comment: Worth mentioning to `ensure` the file is closed after processing if using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you are trying to accomplish is writing to the file. Here's a lightly modified version that echo's what you have written and adds it as a new line in the file:

```
input = 'test.txt'
File.open(input, "w+") do |file| # File open returns the file, not it's lines
  loop do
    puts "Enter line content, or \"-EOF-\" to stop inputting."
    input = gets # no chomp here, because we probably want that in the file
    if input.chomp == "-EOF-" # chomp here to compare with `"-EOF-"` instead of "-EOF-\n"
      break
    else
      file << input # this writes your input line to the file
      puts input
    end
  end
end
```